# Prove that the linear combination $ku + lv$ is also a solution for a system of equations with $u$ and $v$ solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u = (u_1,\dots,u_n)$ and $v = (v_1,\dots,v_n)$ be two solutions to a system of linear equations, and let $k$, $l$ be two real numbers such that $k + l = 1$.

Prove that the linear combination $ku + lv$ is also a solution to the system.

I'm not sure how to begin this proof and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Write the system in matricial form. It's easier to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the system of equations 
$$AX^t=b$$ where $A\in\mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, $b\in\mathcal{M}_{n\times 1}(\mathbb{R})$ and the unknown is $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Since $u,v$ are solutions, it follows that 
$$\begin{cases}Au^t=b\\Av^t=b
\end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases}kAu^t=kb\\lAv^t=lb
\end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases}A(ku)^t=kb\\A(lv)^t=lb
\end{cases}\Rightarrow A(ku+lv)^t=(k+l)b\Rightarrow A(ku+lv)^t=b.$$

Let us write this in detail for $n=2$.

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}\\a_{21} & a_{22}\end{pmatrix},\ b=\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\end{pmatrix}$.

Our system of equations is 
$$\begin{cases} a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2=b_1\\
a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2=b_2\end{cases}.$$

Writing this equation for $u$ and $v$, we get 
$$\begin{cases} a_{11}u_1+a_{12}u_2=b_1\\
a_{21}u_1+a_{22}u_2=b_2\end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases} a_{11}ku_1+a_{12}ku_2=kb_1\\
a_{21}ku_1+a_{22}ku_2=kb_2\end{cases}$$

and

$$\begin{cases} a_{11}lv_1+a_{12}lv_2=lb_1\\
a_{21}lv_1+a_{22}lv_2=lb_2\end{cases}.$$

Summing these, we get

$$\begin{cases} a_{11}ku_1+a_{12}ku_2+a_{11}lv_1+a_{12}lv_2=kb_1+lb_1\\
a_{21}ku_1+a_{22}ku_2+a_{21}lv_1+a_{22}lv_2=kb_2+lb_2\end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases} a_{11}(ku_1+lv_1)+a_{12}(ku_2+lv_2)=(k+l)b_1\\
a_{21}(ku_1+lv_1)+a_{22}(ku_2+lv_2)=(k+l)b_2\end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases} a_{11}(ku_1+lv_1)+a_{12}(ku_2+lv_2)=b_1\\
a_{21}(ku_1+lv_1)+a_{22}(ku_2+lv_2)=b_2\end{cases},$$
which shows that indeed $ku+lv$ is a solution.